# Bookmarklet to turn on Dark Theme on Youtube

Tags: javascript, youtube, bookmarklet

Sorry for posting an unsophisticated question.

I'd like to use Youtube with Dark Mode always on, but sometimes the configurations are reset and I have to click **the icon button**, **Appearance** and then **Dark theme.**
I hope there could be a bookmarklet for this procedure.
And I guess it's not so complicated, only if I had a bit of knowledge.

According to my imagination, the code should look like blow.
How could it be improved? With what search phrase could I find information?

```js
javascript:(function()<br>
{document.getElementById("[ID of Account Menu]").click();}<br>
{document.getElementById("[ID of Appearance]".click();}<br>
{document.getElementById("[ID of Dark theme]".click();}<br>
)();
```

Thanks.

Comment: please dont add sorry or thanks in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: the bookmarklet seems to not do the job if the time is too short so play with the timeouts

```js
javascript: (() => {
  document.getElementById("avatar-btn").click();
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector(".ytd-toggle-theme-compact-link-renderer").click();
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.querySelectorAll(".ytd-compact-link-renderer").forEach(yt => {
        if (yt.textContent === "Dark theme") yt.click();
      });
    }, 1000)
  }, 1000)
})()
```

That said, there is a "Use device theme" you might want to use instead